# 'DocumentReference' object has no attribute 'to_dict'

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using python3 to query a database on firestore. My code is the following:

```
def getWebConsultReData():
    collection = db.collection("webconsult_threescrap").where("compositeKey", "==", "10004-5327729026")
    docs = [snapshot.reference for snapshot in collection.stream()]
    mDictList = []
    print(docs)
    for doc in docs:   
        formattedData = doc.to_dict()
getWebConsultReData()
```

However, I got the following error:

```
[<google.cloud.firestore_v1.document.DocumentReference object at 0x7f2a183413c8>]
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-42-172d5765da1d>", line 9, in <module>
    getWebConsultReData()

  File "<ipython-input-42-172d5765da1d>", line 7, in getWebConsultReData
    formattedData = doc.to_dict()

AttributeError: 'DocumentReference' object has no attribute 'to_dict'
```

What I'm sure are:
The filter is valid, in fact, the following snapshot shows the exact syntax with GUI
[image]

Also the document exists.
Can anybody help me out? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that at the point of the error, `docs` is an array of `DocumentReference`s and not an array of `DocumentSnapshot`s because you remove all the other data a few lines up.  `DocumentReference` only gives a path to the document, it does not contain the entirety of the document's data.

To do something equivalent (gather an array of `DocumentReferences` but also have some access to the actual documents), you'd need to do something like this:

```py
def getWebConsultReData():
    collection = db.collection("webconsult_threescrap").where("compositeKey", "==", "10004-5327729026")
    docs = []
    for doc in collection.stream():   
        formattedData = doc.to_dict()
        print(formattedData)
        docs.append(doc.reference)
    print(docs)
getWebConsultReData()
```

If it helps, you can also review the [example in the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#python_4) of how to get multiple documents from a collection.

Answer (score 0):

```
from google.cloud import firestore

def tableconversations(userdata):
  docarray = []
  db = firestore.Client()
  collection = db.collection('tableQuestions').where('userID', '==', userdata['ID']).get()
  print("user history matched records",collection)
  for doc in collection:
     print(doc.to_dict())
     docarray.append(doc.to_dict())
  return docarray
```